# Probably messed up security after rebuild. Automator actions tagged as malware

Tags: macos-catalina

Last weekend my iMac stopped working (sorry forget the symptom details). I tried Disk Utility but it was unable to fix the issue. After I restarted in recovery mode I was able fix the SSD and HD partitions but ended up with a third item. My fusion drive seemed to be split. I found an Apple Support document: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584 and ran 'diskutil cs create Macintosh\ HD disk0 disk1' from the terminal. This seemed to fix the drive.

I was able restore from Time Machine back-up. Got my old mail from BackBlaze. Seemed OK. However, downloaded files (with Safari) gave an error "File damaged and can't be opened. Drag to Trash". I found a fix for file-by-file repair, i.e. xattr -cr Path-to_file. Seemed to work but tedious and didn't really fix the problem. I thought I might make an Automator Folder action to fix the apparent problem with the extended attributes (addressed by the xattr) command. However, when I dragged an (any?) action into the workflow pane I get an error "The action 'Ask the Finder Items' was not loaded because it was detected as malware.

I'm starting to think there is a global permission flag that needs to be flipped.

Any suggestions ideas. Thanks.

---

Update of sorts. Other files restored from Time Machine are complaining  to be damaged not just new downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported elsewhere I replaced the file /var/db/gkopaque.bundle with the same file from my laptop via Airdrop. So far so good. Files can be opened. Automator also seems to be working.